# Anonymous type declaration works differently via "var" vs ":="

Tags: go

While declaring a variable with anonymous type in Go, I'm seeing `var v` versus `v:=` syntaxes work differently. Imagine we're declaring an empty anonymous struct type instance and assign it to a variable.

This works:

```
func main() {
    var  v struct {}
    _ = v
```

But this does not:

```
func main() {
    t := struct{}
    _ = t
}
```

compiling this gives the following error (https://play.golang.org/p/MgbttbBVmYE):

```
prog.go:8:7: type struct {} is not an expression
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`var v struct{}` gives `v` type `struct{}` but doesn't explicitly set a value, so it gets the zero value `{}`.

`t := struct{}` isn't a complete expression.  You'd need `t := struct{}{}` to create `t` with type `struct {}` and give it the value `{}`.

In other words, `struct{}` is a type, but creating `t` with `:=` needs a value, not just a type on the right side.  `struct{}{}` is how you write the literal form of an anonymous empty struct.

Comment: Ah that makes total sense. How did I miss it!